# Convert Start/End Time into Hourly Intervals PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple form that lets users enter a start time and end time. Upon submission I need to create hourly intervals for every hour between the start and the end time. For example if they selected Start Time '3:00pm' and End Time '7:00pm' I would like to create 4 records in my database as follows:

Start      End
3:00pm     4:00pm
4:00pm     5:00pm
5:00pm     6:00pm
6:00pm     7:00pm

Users are selecting from a select menu with these values:

```
        <option value="10:00am">10:00am</option>
        <option value="11:00am">11:00am</option>
        <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
        <option value="1:00pm">1:00pm</option>
        <option value="2:00pm">2:00pm</option>
        <option value="3:00pm">3:00pm</option>
        <option value="4:00pm">4:00pm</option>
        <option value="5:00pm">5:00pm</option>
        <option value="6:00pm">6:00pm</option>
        <option value="7:00pm">7:00pm</option>
        <option value="8:00pm">8:00pm</option>
        <option value="9:00pm">9:00pm</option>
        <option value="10:00pm">10:00pm</option>
        <option value="11:00pm">11:00pm</option>
```

I'm retrieving the start time and end time like this:

```
$startTime =  $_POST['timeStart'];
$endTime = $_POST['timeEnd'] ;
```

I'm assuming I need to do a foreach but not sure how to grab the time intervals in a loop and set the start/end time for each interval?

Comment: suggestion: switch the `value=` from xx:00pm to using a 24 hour (0-23) method. Than it can be a simple `while` counting from your `timeStart` to `timeEnd` on a very simple 0-23 method, instead of dealing with all of this am/pm crap and trying to clean it up.

Comment: Same premise as @Abela - but I would do it in minutes (range is from 0 - 1440 and you can specify the interval being 30 for every half hour or 60 for each hour) - then on the input you can do the calulation / conversion inbto hours:minutes - also allows you to determine am pm easily. This way you can create a loop to generate the options and their values and it is easy to do duration calcuations etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the conventional approach of using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions and loop through your result.

Try this:

```
$startTime = strtotime($startTime);   /* Find the timestamp of start time */
$endTime = strtotime($endTime);       /* Find the timestamp of end time */
$input = array();
/* Run a loop from start timestamp to end timestamp */
for ($i = $startTime; $i < $endTime; $i+=3600) {
    $input[] = array(
        "start_time" => date("h:ia", $i), 
        "end_time" => date("h:ia", ($i+3600))
    );
}
```

For input `$_POST['timeStart'] = '3:00pm';` and `$_POST['timeEnd'] = '7:00pm';`, the output will be:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [start_time] => 03:00pm
        [end_time] => 04:00pm
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [start_time] => 04:00pm
        [end_time] => 05:00pm
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [start_time] => 05:00pm
        [end_time] => 06:00pm
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
        [start_time] => 06:00pm
        [end_time] => 07:00pm
    )

 )
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks like it will do the trick. Just wondering how do I go about getting the value for each start_time and end_time in the array? (still learning PHP as I go here).

Comment: Do you mean how to use these values in your INSERT query?

Comment: Yes - for each of the start_time/end_time values in the array I need to perform a database operation to create a record. The database code is already set, I just need to know how to get each of the start_time/end_time values in the array?

Comment: I tried this: foreach ($input as $key => $value)  {            echo '<p>'.$key.' - '.$value.'</p>';        } but that doesn't output the key/values

Comment: That wouldn't since this is a multi dimensional array. Try this instead: `echo '<p>'.$value['start_time'].' - '.$value['end_time'].'</p>';`

Comment: Thanks - just realised myself it wouldn't work with a multi dimensional array. Much appreciated.